# How to generate array with elements 0-9 in random order?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to generate an array with 10 elements (0, 1, 2, ..., 9) but in random order. For example:

```
$result = array(5, 3, 1, 2, 9, 8, 7, 4, 6, 0);
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$numbers = range(0,9);
shuffle($numbers);
```

Comment: The return value of `shuffle` is boolean. Also, strict standards will issue a warning for not passing a variable. Do: `$a = range(0, 9); shuffle($a);`

Comment: Answer corrected. Thank you for pointing that out. I guess this one was one I shouldn't have answered off of the top of my head.